# Upon opening new tabs through links in Firefox, does the selected tab automatically switch to the new tab or does it stay on the same tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

That is, say I am on www.google.com

I select a link to say yahoo.com be opened in a new tab.

Does the selected tab automatically shifts to yahoo.com or does it remain on google.com?

This is in regard to a Firefox extension, in which I am assuming this to be true as this is how it is on my browser.

Therefore I want to make if this is a general property or something specific to my version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just go to **Tools>Options**. Now select the **Tab** and find the option

> When I open a link in new tab, switch it to immediately

Now click on the checkbox and click to apply.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Since this option exists, i think it would be safer not to make the assumption i did.

Answer (score 2):

No, by default this option is not enabled in Firefox.

You have to select it from "tools menu - options - tabs - when i open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately".

If this option is not selected, then you will not be automatically redirected to "new tab".

Answer (score 0):

The current tab will remain on google.com, and at your current location on the page.  Yahoo.com will be opened in a new tab. The new tab will become cuurent (or not) according to the option you selected in Firefox's preferences. This is the standard behavior for Firefox IF your extension doesn't modify it.